# Constant Laplacian with some boundary data

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, laplacian

Let $B$ be the open unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, consider
$$
\begin{cases}
\Delta u = c \qquad \text{in} \ B \\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial r} =0 \qquad \text{on} \ \partial B  
\end{cases}
$$
For which values of $c\in \mathbb{R}$ does a solution exist? Is $c=0$ the only possibility?

Comment: Hint: Green's identity

Comment: Thanks it works, I was confused with the notation: $\partial_r$ becomes the normal derivative in this case right?

Comment: $\partial_r$ in general denote the vector field $(x, y) \mapsto \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} } (x, y)$. In this case since $B$ is the unit ball, it is also the normal vector of $\partial B$.